# Append single byte to byte array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, append, arrays

I have a string that I'd like to get the ASCII byte representation of, then add two more single ASCII bytes to the end of.

What is the simplest way to do this? From my searching using Google, it seems that VB's append methods all append only strings and arrays, not characters or bytes... Is this the case?

For example,

```
Dim byte1 As Byte = &H4
Dim byte2 As Byte = &HA

Dim array() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MyTextBox.Text) + byte1 + byte2
```

Then if "ABC" is entered in the text box, the array should end up holding hex `41, 42, 43, 04, 0A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim byte1 As Byte = &H4
    Dim byte2 As Byte = &HA

    Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text & Chr(byte1) & Chr(byte2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two values with:

```
Dim array() as Byte = {byte1, byte2}
```